# MethodError: some problems with JuMP in Julia

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I have some problems with JuMP. When I run it, it says:

```
MethodError: no method matching (::Interpolations.Extrapolation{Float64, 1, ScaledInterpolation{Float64, 1, Interpolations.BSplineInterpolation{Float64, 1, Vector{Float64}, BSpline{Linear{Throw{OnGrid}}}, Tuple{Base.OneTo{Int64}}}, BSpline{Linear{Throw{OnGrid}}}, Tuple{StepRangeLen{Float64, Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}, Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}}}}, BSpline{Linear{Throw{OnGrid}}}, Throw{Nothing}})(::AffExpr)
Use square brackets [] for indexing an Array.
```

thanks!

```
using JuMP
import Ipopt
β = 0.88
Nb = 1000
δ = 1.5
wage = 1
rate = 1
grid_b = range(0, 5, length = 1000)
w = 5 * (grid_b).^2
w_func = LinearInterpolation(grid_b, w)
choice1 = Model(Ipopt.Optimizer)  
@variable(choice1, x >= 0)
@NLobjective(choice1, Max, x^δ/(1-δ) + β * (w_func.((grid_b[3]*(1+rate)+wage-x) * 3))) 
optimize!(choice1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I try to run your code, I get

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: LinearInterpolation not defined
```

which package is that from? Also, what version of JuMP are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t use arbitrary functions in JuMP. You need to use a user-defined function:
https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/manual/nlp/#User-defined-Functions

But this will only work if it’s possible to automatically differentiate the function. I don’t know if that works with Interpolations.jl.

p.s. Please provide a link when posting the same question in multiple places:  https://discourse.julialang.org/t/methoderror-no-method-matching-in-jump/66543/2